# How to return 0 for all time intervals instead of nothing when counting

Tags: sql, postgresql, group-by, conditional-aggregation

I have a query for deployment table. There is no data for hotfix column now. I want to show all change count without hotfix and with hotfix for time intervals.

Table data:

| deployTime | changeno | hotfix |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 2022-08 | aaa |  |
| 2022-08 | bbb |  |
| 2022-11 | ccc |  |
| 2023-01 | ddd |  |

First attempted query:

```
SELECT deployTime               AS times ,   
       COUNT(DISTINCT changeno) AS "Change Count" 
FROM deployments 
WHERE hotfix = ''
GROUP BY deployTime
```

which returns all dates with Change count:

| times | ChangeCount |
| --- | --- |
| 2022-08 | 2 |
| 2022-11 | 1 |
| 2023-01 | 1 |

Second attempted query:

```
SELECT deployTime               AS times ,   
       COUNT(DISTINCT changeno) AS "Change Count" 
FROM deployments 
WHERE hotfix != ''
GROUP BY deployTime
```

which returns no records if there's no record with `hotfix != ''`.

How we can get 0 count for every date instead of nothing?

| times | HotfixCount |
| --- | --- |
| 2022-08 | 0 |
| 2022-11 | 0 |
| 2023-01 | 0 |

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem with your query is that you're using a `WHERE` clause, that removes records. What you should do instead, is apply conditional aggregation on presence/absence of hotfix values:

```
SELECT deployTime AS times ,   
       COUNT(DISTINCT changeno) FILTER(WHERE hotfix = '') AS "Change Count" 
FROM deployments 
GROUP BY deployTime
```

And change it to `WHERE NOT hotfix = ''` conversely to obtain zeroes.

Check the demo [here](https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/fNWBN562cXkXQbcmgaBVni/1).

Note: It's better to have `NULL` values instead of empty strings, when you need to indicate missing data.

Answer (score 1):

You can do it using the conditional aggregation :

```
    select deployTime as times ,   
           sum(case when hotfix then 1 else 0 end) as "Change Count" 
    from deployments 
    group by deployTime
```